# Compute $\int_{|r|=2}\frac{1}{z^2+1}dz$

Tags: complex-numbers, contour-integration, complex-integration

Compute $\int_{|r|=2}\frac{1}{z^2+1}dz$. 
Is there a special trick to solving this? I tried letting $z(t)=2e^{it},t\in[0,2\pi]$, which gave me 
$$\int_{|z|=2}\frac{1}{z^2+1}dz=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{2ie^{it}}{4e^{2it}+1}dt=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{2i}{4e^{it}+e^{-it}}dt$$
but that doesn't seem to make it any easier. 
Is there a bettergeneral method to computing imaginary integrals along the circumference of fixed circle like this, maybe using Cauchy's formula?

Comment: Try the residue theorem.

Comment: You know residues's theorem?

Comment: @vvnitram: You have some residual 's's :-).

Comment: Is that the standard method for solving integrals of this type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's problem in it... It's simple to integrate further ... 
Use your second Integral ... No need to divide $e^{it}$ in the numerator and denominator.
Use substitution $x=e^{it}$ 
And integrate directly... You will get 
$$[\tan^{-1}(2e^{ix})]$$ 
Put the limits...

You will get $\boxed{0}$ as answer.